Nesting a drop down inside a section in a dynamic javascript form
I'm trying to use a drop down next to a simple number input within a section on a dynamic web page form. I am able to create a new section with a button, and I can use normal text or number fields within that section. However when I try and create a drop down within a section I cannot get it to work.
I can get the dropdown to work fine when its independent, just not within the dynamically created section.
document.getElementById('addVegetablesButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var newSection = document.createElement('fieldset');
  var legend = document.createElement('legend');
  legend.textContent = 'Vegetable';

  var newField1 = document.createElement('input');
  newField1.type = 'number';
  newField1.name = 'sectionField1';
  newField1.placeholder = 'Quantity';
    
  var newField2 = document.createElement('label');
  newField2.textContent = 'Vegetable type:';

  var newSelect = document.createElement('select');
  newSelect.name = 'dynamicSelect';

  var option1 = document.createElement('option');
  option1.value = 'option1';
  option1.textContent = 'Carrot';

  var option2 = document.createElement('option');
  option2.value = 'option2';
  option2.textContent = 'Brussel Sprout';

  newSelect.appendChild(option1);
  newSelect.appendChild(option2);
    
  newSection.appendChild(legend);
  newSection.appendChild(newField1);
  newSection.appendChild(newField2);
  document.getElementById('dynamicForm').appendChild(newSection);
});


With the above the first element (quantity) works fine, the label for the newField2 shows, but no drop down. I tried various configurations where the button woldn't even generate the section, the above is as close as I have come to it work.

You forgot to append newSelect: newSection.appendChild(newSelect);

Hadn't realised this wouldn't remain as a ref to newField2, you are correct though thank you very much!
